# Can I use VBA to tell if my spreadsheet was opened by a user vs. a linked document?

Tags: excel, vba

## The Problem

I have an Excel workbook that prompts the user for some actions every time it is opened.

This same workbook contains charts that are linked in a PowerPoint file.  These links were created by copying the charts in Excel and then, in the PowerPoint file, clicking "Paste Special", choosing "Paste Link", and selecting "Microsoft Excel Worksheet (code) Object" as the link type.

Every time the PowerPoint file is opened, I am prompted to update the links in the document.

The trouble is that, while PowerPoint is updating links, the Excel prompts that are intended for the user are shown and have to be clicked (multiple times) during the link update process.

Is it possible for my VBA code to detect when it's being opened for the purposes of updating links so I can skip the user prompts?  I should note, in case it matters, that I'm using Microsoft Office 365 on Windows 10.

## What I've Tried

I've tried monitoring the value of ThisWorkbook.ReadOnly, Application.Interactive, and Application.IsSandboxed during startup, but they all appear to have the same values regardless of whether the workbook is opened for the purposes of updating links or not.  I'm not familiar enough with how link updating works to know what else to check for.

I've identified a couple of possible work-arounds:

First, if the Excel workbook is opened before PowerPoint is opened and the link update process starts, then the prompts don't appear.  This will work, if there's no better solution.

Second, I could create a second "shadow" Excel workbook with charts generated from data in the first spreadsheet, but without user prompts.  If PowerPoint links to the charts in the "shadow" workbook, then links are updated without issue.  This is far from ideal because of the need to keep the two workbooks in sync.

I'm hoping for an elegant automated solution.

Comment: You could have your startup triggered code in WB2 check to see if WB1 is open. And if you might sometimes have both open, you could add a hidden sheet on WB1. Every time you run your code to open WB2, change the boolean value of A1 on that hidden sheet to true, then change it to false when you're done. The startup code in WB2 can check that boolean to see if it needs to run.

Comment: Interesting idea.  I'll have to give that some thought.  Thank you!

Comment: Would it be Ok if there was a few seconds delay before the prompt appeared to the user when they open the workbook?